# separate .txt file to csv file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, awk, split

trying to convert txt file to csv but doesnt work

orginal text:

```
 استقالة #رئيس_القضاء #السودان  OBJ
أهنئ الدكتور أحمد جمال الدين، مناسبة صدور أولى روايته   POS
يستقوى بامريكا مرةاخرى و يرسل عصام العريان الي واشنطن شئ NEG
#انتخبوا_العرص #انتخبوا_البرص #مرسى_رئيسى  #_ #__ö  NEUTRAL
```

expected result :

```
text                                                             value
استقالة #رئيس_القضاء #السودان                                   OBJ
أهنئ الدكتور أحمد جمال الدين، مناسبة صدور أولى روايته         POS
يستقوى بامريكا مرةاخرى و يرسل عصام العريان الي واشنطن شئ      NEG
#انتخبوا_العرص #انتخبوا_البرص #مرسى_رئيسى  #_ #__ö             NEUTRAL
```

i have tried this but its doesn't work for space and comma constrain

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "text,value"}{print $1","$2"}' ifile.txt
```

also i have tired this with python but it doesn't contain all of them

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_fwf('log.txt')
df.to_csv('log.csv')
```

Comment: Trivially, the `"`s are mis-aligned.

Answer (score 1):

Your request is unclear, how do you want to format the last field.

I created a script that align the last line on column 60.

script.awk

```
BEGIN {printf("text%61s\n","value")}  # formatted printing heading line
{
    lastField = $NF;               # store current last field into var
    $NF = "";                      # remove last field from line
    alignLen =  60 - length() + length(lastField); # compute last field alignment
    alignFormat = "%s%"alignLen"s\n";   # create printf format for computed alignment
    printf(alignFormat, $0, lastField); # format print current line and last field
}
```

run `script.awk`

```
awk -f script.awk ifile.txt
```

output

```
text                                                        value
استقالة #رئيس_القضاء #السودان                               OBJ
أهنئ الدكتور أحمد جمال الدين، مناسبة صدور أولى روايته       POS
يستقوى بامريكا مرةاخرى و يرسل عصام العريان الي واشنطن شئ    NEG
#انتخبوا_العرص #انتخبوا_البرص #مرسى_رئيسى #_ #__ö           NEUTRAL
```

Comment: its doesn't work, i have file contains 10k lines and it both all of them on one col

Comment: It works with the sample data you posted in the question. Try posting more sample data, when it does not work. Maybe you need longer allignment at columns 80?